# How to define and use precompiled variable in delphi directives

Tags: delphi, directive, precompile

I want to define a precompile string variable and use it in {$include} directive in delphi, for example:

```
{$define FILE_NAME "lockfile"}
{$include FILE_NAME'.txt.1'}
{$include FILE_NAME'.txt.2'}
...
```

For security reasons (this is part of our licensing system), we don't want to use normal strings and file reading functions. Is there any capability for this purpose in Delphi?

Comment: `$INCLUDE` is used to paste source code into your code at compile time. Are you sure that's what you want to do? In other words, the compiler will process these files as Delphi source code and compile them into executable code. Perhaps you wish to link the text as a resource. Do note that this won't increase security. Linked resources or aux text files are just as visible. It looks like you are going to attempt to write security features that are insecure.

Comment: @Hossein Like David said, it looks as if you are preparing 'source' files for each licensee, and then make a unique build for them. But in that case, why not just make *one* lockfile.txt to $include? It looks like we need more info. [What problem are your trying to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @David I want to include some constant keys and queries into my code before compile, but they are different for each customer (We compile code for each customer). I don't want to attach them as a data file or resource, because I think compiled constant is more difficult to hack.

Comment: @Jan I added some verification codes in different places of my code (because I think it's harder to be hacked), therefor many $INCLUDE commands exists in my code with different "file_name" included. We can just replace included files with new ones and compile code for each customer, but I wonder if there exists a precompile variable that I use it as a file name or file path in my $INCLUDE command.

Comment: FWIW, I doubt you are making your code any harder to hack

Comment: Why don't you put each different lock file in a different directory, one per customer. Then as part of your build process include each specific directory in the search path when you build for separate customers.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful hint. I'll do it. But I'm still curious to answer of this question: "Are there any precompile variable in delphi?"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "precompile variable". Can you elaborate?

Comment: AFAIK - unless it was chanced in some recent version of Delphi, $I will interpret its parameter as a filename, not as a variable, so you can't "build" a constant and pass it to $I, nor does it supports string chaining, Delphi directives don't work as a C/C++ preprocessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$INCLUDE` directive does not support indirection on the file name. So, the following code:

```
const
  someconst = 'foo';

{$INCLUDE someconst}
```

leads to the following error:

```
F1026 File not found: 'someconst.pas'
```

If you must use an include file, you must apply the indirection by some other means. One way could be to use the fact that the compiler will search for the included file by looking on the search path. So, if you place each client specific include file in a different directory, then you can add the client specific directory to the search path as part of your build process.

FWIW, I find it hard to believe that this will make your program more immune to hacking. I think that a more likely outcome is that your program will be just as susceptible to hacking, but that it will become much more difficult and error prone for you to build and distribute the program.

Answer (score 1):

You requirement may be better satisfied by the proper use of a VCS system. You need "branches" for every customer where customer-specific files contains customer-specific data. This will avoid to litter your code with complex directive to manage each customer - file names stays the same, just their content is different in each branch. Adding a new customer just requires to create a new branch and update files there.

Then you just need get each branch and compile it for each customer to get the final executable(s) with customer specific data built in.

Comment: It's not going to be much fun when you release version 2 of the software and have to update hundreds of branches. That sounds like a very flaky approach to me. In fact I'd say that using VCS branches, one per customer, is a exceedingly bad use of VCS and a very poor solution.

Comment: You can have branches only for customer specific files, which should contain a few short files each - a project never needs to be contained in a "single" branch - you can use files from several different branches as long as they don't overlap.
And of course it may not a feasible solution for "hundreds" of customers, but if your application has just a few of them it would work perfectly.
It looks to me many uses VCS software at 10% of its power, mainly to store versions, and not to perform full configuration management.